# Blank Database Entry Gives Error

Tags: django, multiple-databases

This is My Settings.py:

```
         DATABASES = {
             'default': {},
             'company': {
                 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                 'NAME': 'leavebuddy_company',
                 'USER': 'leavebuddy_user2',
                 'PASSWORD': '******',
                 'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
                 'PORT': '3306',
}
```

}

Its Giving me the error:

```
           settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Can you guys please guide me in the right direction.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You **must** define a default database. As per [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases) (emphasis mine):

> The `DATABASES` setting **must** configure a `default` database; any number of additional databases may also be specified.

---

Unless you're going to be using multiple databases, you do not need a `default` and a `company` database.

Just use:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'leavebuddy_company',
        'USER': 'leavebuddy_user2',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using multiple databases but i dont want the default database.
as per the doc, its possible but in my case its not working.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @Shivratna You don't really have a choice when using Django... The default database must be defined. Just use one of your multiple databases as default.